# Python Genshi benchmarking

Tags: python, profiling, genshi

I greatly enjoy profiling my Python code with [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler), which gives me a rundown on how much time is spent in what line of source code. Is there a way to do this for [Genshi templates](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Genshi)? There are a few templates in my code base that are slow and contain a lot of display logic, and cProfile's output is too opaque for identifying the bottlenecks.